# jQuery audio stop/pause on change

Tags: jquery, audio

How to stop/pause jQuery audio on change?

```
$("#alarm").bind("change", function(event)
{
    var audio = $(this).find(':selected').attr('data-audio');

    var obj = document.createElement("audio");
    obj.src="assets/audio/"+audio;
    obj.volume=0.1;
    obj.autoPlay=false;
    obj.preLoad=true;
    obj.play();
});
```

I tried to added `obj.pause();` before `obj.play();` but it still run the music. So if I change to another combobox the audio will play multiple.

What I want is stop/pause the audio on change.

HTML

```
<select name="alarm" id="alarm">
    <?php
    $qAlarm = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tb_alarm WHERE active = 'Y'");
    while($dAlarm = mysqli_fetch_array($qAlarm))
    {
        if($dAlarm['alarm_id'] == $getAlarmID)
        {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $dAlarm['alarm_id']; ?>" selected data-audio=<?php echo $dAlarm['alarm_file']; ?>><?php echo $dAlarm['alarm_name']; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        else
        {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $dAlarm['alarm_id']; ?>" data-audio=<?php echo $dAlarm['alarm_file']; ?>><?php echo $dAlarm['alarm_name']; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Please include your html code

Comment: Instead obj.pause(); do obj.src = ''; This is not an ideal way to do that but it's a quick fix.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen html code added

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really make sense to pause the music and in the next line start it, does it? If you want to pause the music on change, don't put the code for starting the music in the onChange function. 
Try to start the music somewhere else, maybe when the document finished loading and in the change function just run pause:

```
var audio = $('#audioelement');
obj.pause();
```

Be sure to give the audio-object an id when creating it:

```
obj.id = "audioelement";
```

Comment: Okay I edited the post, try again. Where are you starting the audio now?